# How to report progress of a background worker created and running in another class to UI

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, backgroundworker

I have a button which calls a class to initiate a background worker. Everything works fine, except I want to report progress to the UI(which has the button) to be updated with background worker progress changed. I Have tried a lot things but could not succeed. The progress changed does not simply fires.

Here is the code for initiate background worker:

```
var backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            ListBackgroundWorkerRunning.Add(path, backgroundWorker);
            backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            backgroundWorker.DoWork += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    _fileUploadRepository.UploadFiles(path);
                    var directoryConfiguration = new DirectoryConfiguration();
                    directoryConfiguration.UpdateProgressBarHandler(10);
                    //BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

                    //directoryConfiguration.ProgressChanged += directoryConfiguration_ProgressChanged;
                };
            //backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged;
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    _crudOperation.UpdateDatabaseWithCrawlFinishedNotification(path);
                    RemoveCrawler(path);
                    InitializeWatcher(path);
                };
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Here is progress_changed event :

```
//void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        //{
        //    var directoryConfiguration = new DirectoryConfiguration();
        //    directoryConfiguration.Invoke(new Action(() => directoryConfiguration.progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage));
        //}
```

Answer (score 0):

You still have to call

```
backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(currentProgress);
```

from your DoWork handler from time to time in order to trigger a progress event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4.aspx

You will also have to comment in your ProgressChanged handler again :-)

Comment: Well I have done that and background worker does not even fire up the progress changed event. And please note that my UI and background worker are in different thread. In UI thread I have a progress bar which need to have the progress value which should be passed from background worker progress changed event.